# Camera video and taking a picture with Python Kivy

Tags: python, multithreading, image, camera, kivy

I am using a screen manager and wish that when visiting ScreenThree the
camera image is displayed. I wish to use the cv2 camera code. Upon clicking a button I would like a picture to be captured then execute code using that image.
So far I have a threaded version I found on the internet that works well displaying camera input. Getting a picture captured by clicking on a button is defeating my efforts.

Screen3 contains a place for video and a button to execute code to take a picture.

```
<ScreenThree>:
    name: "screenthree"
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            id: vid    #Vido image
            pos_hint: {'x':0.0, 'y':0.2}
            size_hint: 1.0, 0.8
        Image:
            source: "clue.png" # Decorative image
            size_hint:(0.20,0.20)
            pos_hint: {"x":0.05,"y":0.75}
        Button:
            text: "Click to scan"
            background_color : 0, 0, 1, 1
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25,"y":0.85}
            on_press: root.takepic()
        Button:
            text: "Go to next screen"      # Screen4
            background_color : 1, 0, 1, 1
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.45,"y":0.85}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_four'
```

The threading code is ( I don't know what the hidden window is about);

```
class ScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.doit, daemon=True).start()
        self.new_screen = ScreenThree()
        return screen_manager

    def doit(self):
        self.do_vid = True
        cv2.namedWindow('Hidden', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL | cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO)
        cv2.resizeWindow('Hidden', 0, 0)
        cam=cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0', cv2.CAP_V4L)

        while (self.do_vid):
            ret, frame = cam.read()
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.display_frame, frame))
            cv2.imshow('Hidden', frame)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
        cam.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def display_frame(self, frame, dt):
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture.blit_buffer(frame.tobytes(order=None), colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        texture.flip_vertical()

        self.root.get_screen('screen_three').ids.vid.texture = texture
```

I put code that capture the image in ScreenThree Class. Clicking on the button transfers to the takepic() method but fails reading the image, crashing when trying to write an empty image. The camera on /dev/video0 is still held by the threaded code. How can I get access to the camera to capture a picture or how do I prompt the threaded routine to take the picture for me.

```
class ScreenThree(Screen):
    def takepic(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0', cv2.CAP_V4L)

        # set dimensions
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

        # take frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # write frame to file
        cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', frame)
        # release camera
        cap.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your thread is already capturing frames from the camera, you can just use the current frame that has been captured, like this:

```
def doit(self):
    self.do_vid = True
    self.frame = None  # add reference to the current frame
    cv2.namedWindow('Hidden', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL | cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO)
    cv2.resizeWindow('Hidden', 0, 0)
    cam=cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0', cv2.CAP_V4L)

    while (self.do_vid):
        ret, self.frame = cam.read()  # save the current frame
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.display_frame, self.frame))
        cv2.imshow('Hidden', self.frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Use the current frame in the `takepic()` method:

```
class ScreenThree(Screen):
    def takepic(self):
        # get current frame
        frame = App.get_running_app().frame
        # write frame to file
        cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', frame)
```

Comment: I did not know App.get_running_app() existed, Great!. This could be the answer except the fame object obtained in takepic is NoneType and it crashes trying to write the image. The threaded method doit() shows the frame object is <class 'numpy.ndarray'> and besides the camera images appear in the window so the frame is complete there..

Comment: Did you remember to modify the line: `ret, self.frame = cam.read()  # save the current frame`? Note the `self.frame`.

Comment: Yes that is right and it works now. i could make up a generic working version and post that. Is that appropriate?

Comment: Sometimes people do that and post it as another answer. That would make it easier for other people who may be searching for the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from Mr John Anderson, this generic code works and may be useful for others.

```
"""
 Sets up multiple screens with transitions between screens.
 From Screen three the camera imaging appears.
 There may be a delay before appearing
 A button labeled Click to take" captures and stores the camera image
"""
import threading
from functools import partial
import kivy
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from PIL import Image as Pimage
from kivy.config import Config
import numpy
import cv2
# Builder is used when .kv file is in .py file
from kivy.lang import Builder

# The screen manager is a widget
# dedicated to managing multiple screens for your application.
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)

# You can create your kv code in the Python file
Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "This is screen one"
            font_size: 48
            background_color : 0, 0, 1, 1
            on_press:
                # Define the duration of the change and the direction of the slide
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'
<ScreenTwo>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        background_color: 1,1,1,1
#        Image:
#            source: "somepic.png"
#            size_hint:(0.7,0.35)
#            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
#            allow_stretch: True
#            keep_ratio: False

        Button:
            text: "Screen Two press to change screen"
            font_size: 34
            font_name: 'AbyssinicaSIL-R'
            background_color : 1, 1, 0, 1
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
<ScreenThree>:
    name: "screenthree"
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            id: vid
            pos_hint: {'x':0.0, 'y':0.2}
            size_hint: 1.0, 0.8
#        Image:
#            source: "Somepic2.png"
#            size_hint:(0.20,0.20)
#            pos_hint: {"x":0.05,"y":0.75}
        Button:
            text: "Click to scan"
            background_color : 0, 0, 1, 1
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25,"y":0.85}
            on_press: root.takepic()
        Button:
            text: "Go to next screen"      #Goes to Screen4
            background_color : 1, 0, 1, 1
            size_hint: 0.2,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x":0.45,"y":0.85}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_four'
        Label:
            id:notif
            text:"Wait for camera image."
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {"x":0.2,"y":0.1}
<ScreenFour>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Go to Screen 5"
            background_color : 0, 1, 1, 1
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_one'
""")
# Create a class for all screens in which you can include
# helpful methods specific to that screen
class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenThree(Screen):
    def takepic(self):
        kk = App.get_running_app()
        frame = App.get_running_app().frame
        pdb.set_trace()
        cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', frame)

class ScreenFour(Screen):
    pass

# The ScreenManager controls moving between screens
screen_manager = ScreenManager()

# Add the screens to the manager and then supply a name
# that is used to switch screens
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name ="screen_one"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name ="screen_two"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenThree(name ="screen_three"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenFour(name ="screen_four"))
# Create the App class
class ScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.doit, daemon=True).start()
        self.new_screen = ScreenThree()
        return screen_manager

    def doit(self):
        self.do_vid = True
        self.frame=None
        cv2.namedWindow('Hidden', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL | cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO)
        cv2.resizeWindow('Hidden', 0, 0)
        cam=cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0', cv2.CAP_V4L)

        while (self.do_vid):
            ret, self.frame = cam.read()
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.display_frame, self.frame))
            cv2.imshow('Hidden', self.frame)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
        cam.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def display_frame(self, frame, dt):
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture.blit_buffer(frame.tobytes(order=None), colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        texture.flip_vertical()
        self.root.get_screen('screen_three').ids.vid.texture = texture

# run the app
sample_app = ScreenApp()
sample_app.run()
```